# How to update form values that are nested inside an object

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to update some values that are nested inside an object but they are unable to change.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-breeze-nyzy3

The values that are not updating in form are:

```
parcel_attributes: {
      name= "",
      sku= "",
      quantity=""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create another handleChange `handleChangeParcel` like this for `parcel_attributes`.

```
  const handleChangeParcel = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      parcel_attributes: {
        ...formData.parcel_attributes,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  ...

    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChangeParcel}
      value={formData.parcel_attributes.name}
      name="name"
    />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-worker-3jcil

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, you can also do this with a single function if you check the nested properties are in the object or not using `in` operator. Just check whether the property we are changing is direct or nested and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single function `handleChange` to change the value but you have to figure out nested value should be handle separately:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-christian-oyppm?file=/src/App.js)

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  if (!(e.target.name in formData.parcel_attributes)) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  } else {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      parcel_attributes: {
        ...formData.parcel_attributes,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      },
    });
  }
};
```